# "Failed to parse server response" when using Google Assistant SDK with GRPC in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc, google-assistant-sdk

I've created a bidirectional stream with `assistant.converse()`, and sending audio is successful.

```
const assistant = new protocol.EmbeddedAssistant(ASSISTANT_API_ENDPOINT, credentials);
const conversation = assistant.converse();
conversation.on('data', data => {
  console.log(data);
});

conversation.on('error', err => {
  console.log(err);
  micStream.end();
});
conversation.write({ config }); // audio type config
micStream // an object that provides an audio stream
  .pipe(through2.obj((chunk, enc, cb) => cb(null, { 'audio_in': chunk })))
  .pipe(conversation);
```

When I stop talking and Assistant detects silence, the Assistant throws this error:

```
{ Error: Failed to parse server response
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/Users/arilotter/Projects/assistant/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:201:19)
    at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/Users/arilotter/Projects/assistant/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:180:8)
    at /Users/arilotter/Projects/assistant/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:649:14 code: 13, metadata: undefined }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, but "Failed to parse server response" is an error generated on the client when the response message doesn't match the expected format.

Comment: @murgatroid999 I can't under why the response message wouldn't match the expected format when the .proto file is provided by Google

Comment: can you show the content of the `config` and `conversation` objects?